# Force browser to view/download latest version of PDF?

Tags: wordpress, pdf, caching, version

We host over 100 PDFs that are updated regularly on our website for download. The filename always remains the same, but the file itself is replaced. The whole folder is nothing but these PDFs. But, some users seem to be opening cached versions of the PDF, not the latest-and-greatest versions. Is there a way to force browsers to open or download the latest versions and not the cached versions? This is a Wordpress site.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have access to the server configuration, you can try a cache busting variable to the links.

```
?cache_killer=1234567890
```

```
add_filter('the_content', function( $content ) {
  return preg_replace("/href=(.*?\.pdf)/", '$0?ck='.time(), $content);
}, 10);
```

I am making the assumption that your links are inside the post's content. This might not work if you are using server-side caching.

Answer (score 0):

If using apache, you can user **mod_expires** and set the default expiration for pdf files to the time in which the user retrieves the file.

In order to enable mod_expires in apache (it usually comes with the default installation of apache 2.4), you can execute:

```
# a2enmod expires
Enabling module expires.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  systemctl restart apache2
# systemctl restart apache2
```

Now you can modify the `.htaccess` file of Wordpress and add the next content:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType application/pdf A0
</IfModule>
```

You can read more on this in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30137671)